# Relation between interaction Lagrangian and interaction Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, field-theory, constrained-dynamics

I work with this interaction Lagrangian density

$$\mathcal{L}_{int} = ia\bar{\Psi}\gamma^\mu\Psi Z_\mu +ib(\phi^\dagger\partial_\mu \phi - \partial_\mu\phi^\dagger \phi)Z^\mu,$$

where $Z^\mu$ is an hermitian vector field, $\phi$ is a complex scalar field and $\Psi$ is the field of the electron (I think they are interaction picture fields, it's not specified).

I need to find the Feynman rules for this interaction. I would like to find them in two different ways: both using a Hamiltonian formalism and Lagrangian formalism (path integral).

In order to work with an Hamiltonian formalism, I need to find $\mathcal{H}_{int}$. That's my problem. How to find it? Since $\mathcal{L}_{int} = \mathcal{L}_{int}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi,…)$, I can't say simply $\mathcal{H}_{int} = - \mathcal{L}_{int}$.

Comment: Why do you not just do the Legendre transform to get the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Because there is the constraint due to vector field.

Comment: Yeah, so the Hamiltonian formulation is going to be a bit complicated. Still, what about the standard treatment of such constrained Hamiltonian systems doesn't lead you to a Hamiltonian?

Comment: ACuriousMind the fact is that I would like to know the standard treatment and if this is a simple case. The questions is very simple and clear....

Comment: ...yeah, this *is* a bit complicated. Have you seen the standard quantization of electromagnetism? The "standard" procedure is known as "Dirac quantization", but the more powerful and general method for quantizing constrained theories is the BRST formalism. There are entire *books* written about this, one can't do it justice in a phys.SE answer. In the end, you'll find probably that you actually *don't* want to work with the Hamiltonian formulation.